# Write the file name before deleting

Tags: bash, gnu-findutils

I want to delete all the .png files in a directory and save the delete files names in a text file. I managed to do this with the following command:

```
find . -name "*.png" -delete -print >> log.txt
```

Everything works fine and in the log I get the entire the path of the file deleted. But if there are multiple files to be deleted, the names placed in the log are all on the same line.

```
C:/Users/Dragos.Cazangiu/Desktop/TesteCyg/CMDER/New Bitmap Image3.pngC:/Users/Dragos.Cazangiu/Desktop/TesteCyg/CMDER/2.pngC:/Users/Dragos.Cazangiu/Desktop/TesteCyg/CMDER/New Bitmap Image.png
```

How can I make it put each file on a new line and also how can I add a message before the path, something like "The deleted file is: "

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `-print` predicate with this predicate:

```
-exec printf 'The deleted file is: %s\n' {} \;
```

so that the command looks like:

```
find . -name "*.png" -delete -exec printf 'The deleted file is: %s\n' {} \; >> log.txt
```

If you have GNU `find`, then you can use the `-printf` predicate as so:

```
find . -name "*.png" -delete -printf 'The deleted file is: %p\n' >> log.txt
```

Comment: I don't see the point of explicitly printf `\n`. This is actually the default. Also the `{} \;` is wrong here. It is a syntax specific to the `-exec` option. Wonder why this has been accepted.

Comment: I admit that I missed that you `-exec printf`.. But that's more or less the same. You are still outputting `\n` which is the default.

Comment: @hek2mgl: what else would you want instead of `\n`? nothing? or `\r\n` since OP seems to be on a retarded OS?

Comment: I recommended to use `\r\n` in my answer and this is what makes sense for me. Don't get me wrong, I'm just curious why the OP is fine with your answer. Actually I don't understand the question then.

Comment: @hek2mgl: I guess OP was more interested in knowing how to print a message around the file name (the `-exec printf`/`-printf` part)... go figure why mine got accepted and not yours. SO is a bit weird sometimes — look at Adelani's answer that got an upvote.

Comment: Yeah, that for sure but still I'm asking why OP missed the newlines (Look at the sample output in the question). At the end we'll probably never know... :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on Windows (for whatever reason... ;) ) you may want to use `-printf` in order to produce Windows style line endings:

```
find . -name '*.png*' -delete -printf "%p\r\n" >> log.txt
```

Alternatively just configure the text editor you are using to view the output file to UNIX line endings.

To add a message:

```
find . -name '*.png*' -delete -printf "Deleted: %p\r\n" >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

> find . -name "*.png" -delete -print "\n" >> log.txt

Answer (score 1):

A much more intuitive (TGIF :) way by using bash, `rm`, `yes` and awk. First, test stuff:

```
$ touch 1.png 2.png 3.png
```

Then:

```
for i in *.png ; do yes | rm -i $i 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk '{gsub(/^.|..$/,"",$NF);print $NF}' >> file ; done
$ cat file
1.png
2.png
3.png
```

or:

```
for i in *.png                                       # daloop
do                                                   # yes sir
  yes |                                              # nod to pipe
  rm -i $i 2>&1 >/dev/null |                         # rm interactively piping the stderr
  awk '{ gsub(/^.|..$/,"",$NF); print $NF }' >> file # ... to awk
done                                                 # phew
```

Quote `$i` if needed.

Comment: How is that more intuitive?

Comment: @hek2mgl You probably missed that :) right after _intuitive_ and _TGIF_...

Comment: Yeah, looks like I missed that